# Selecting data from two tables with sql query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

Course ( ID Date Description Duration Meatier_ID Promotion_ID).

second table

Ensign( E_Id Meatier_Id Promotion_Id)

infarct i have an id based on that id i have to Select data from Ensign where id=Eng_Id then i need to select data from Course where Meatier_Id and Promotion_Id in table Course are equal to Meatier_Id and Promotion_Id to data selected in earlier query

can i do it using one S q l query thanks

Br
Sara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the two tables together on Meater_ID and Promotion_ID. Then select those rows where Eng_Id is the id you are working with.

```
SELECT *
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN Ensign e
   ON e.Meatier_ID = c.Meatier_ID
  AND e.Promotion_ID = c.Promotion_ID
WHERE e.Eng_Id = <id value here>
```

EDIT:

The above should work for SQL Server. For derby, try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Course
INNER JOIN Ensign 
  ON Ensign.Meatier_ID = Course.Meatier_ID
 AND Ensign.Promotion_ID = Course.Promotion_ID
WHERE Ensign.Eng_Id = <id value here>
```

Comment: I am trying to join the tables but it doesn't let me auto-complete on after join

Comment: infact after the Inner Join it wont let me complete the name of the Entity therefore i guess its not working what do u suggest

Comment: What environment are you working in? SqlServerManagementStudio? Can you do 'SELECT * FROM Course' and 'SELECT * FROM Ensign' without problems?

Comment: yes i can infact i am using derby the built in database i can very welll select from these 2 tables separately

Comment: and i can not test my commands because these are the command written in hibernate so i have to rely on auto complete to verify that the command will work or not

Comment: From the tag, I assumed you were using sql-server-2008? I'm not familiar with derby but after a quick Google, please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit vague, But I gave it a try

```
--These two variables take the place for your 'Earlier Query' values
DECLARE @Meatier_ID INT = 100,
        @Promotion_Id INT = 15

--The query
SELECT *
FROM Course AS C
INNER JOIN Ensign AS E ON C.ID = E.E_Id
WHERE C.Meatier_ID = @Meatier_ID
AND C.Promotion_Id = @Promotion_Id
```

Comment: infact the matching parameter is a variable that i recieve in a function. so based on that i have to select data from Engseine Where Eng_Id=variable id and then based on that record set i have to select data from Cours c where c.matiere.id and c.promotion.id must b equal to id selected in earlier record set...if thats clear im sorry

Answer (score 0):

select e.E_Id, e.Meatier_Id, e.Promotion_Id, c.ID, c.Date, c.Description, c.Duration from Ensign as e inner join course as c where  e.Meatier_Id=c.Meatier_Id and e.Promotion_Id=c.Promotion_Id and e.E_Id=@Eng_Id